# Как сделать так, чтобы карточка перевернулась с помощью css click-event, используя input?

Tags: html, css, css-animation, checkbox

Я пытаюсь перевернуть карточку с помощью CSS click-event, используя input, который скрыт.
Каждый раз, когда пользователь щелкает по карточке, она будет переворачиваться и отображать содержимое на обратной стороне.
При повторном клике, карточка снова перевернется на вид спереди.

Вот мой фрагмент кода для получения дополнительной информации:

```css
.container {
  padding: 12rem;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.tile {
  perspective: 100rem;
  -moz-perspective: 100rem;
  position: relative;
  width: 50%;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-right: 5rem;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}
.tile-back, .tile-front {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
.tile-back {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
.tile-back, .tile-back .card-body {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  width: 50%;
  text-align: center;
}

.card {
  background-color: #58AA3F;
  height: 20rem;
  transition: all .8s ease;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  border-radius: 5px;
  overflow: hidden;
  box-shadow: 0 1.5rem 4rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -webkit-transition: all 600ms;
  transition: all 600ms;
  z-index: 20;
}
.card div {
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}
.card-body {
  font-size: 2rem;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
}
.card-footer {
  font-size: 2rem;
}
.card:hover .card {
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(20deg);
  transform: rotateX(20deg);
  box-shadow: 0 20px 20px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.2);
}
.card input {
  display: none;
}
.card :checked + .card {
  transform: rotateX(180deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(180deg);
}
.card:hover :checked + .card {
  transform: rotateX(160deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(160deg);
  box-shadow: 0 20px 20px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
}
```

```html
<div class="tile">
   <input type="checkbox"/>
     <div class="card tile-front">
        <div class="card-body">
            <p>Click to display back</p>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="card tile-back">
         <div class="card-body">
            <p>Click to display front</p>
         </div>
      </div>
</div>
```

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [How can I make a card flip with css click-event using an input box?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52239265/7394871) от участника  [@stephdev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10335831/stephdev).</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/52239265/7394871

Answer (score 3):

Я сделал несколько изменений в вашем коде. Для ясности я оставил checkbox видимым, но вы можете скрыть его.

```css
label[for=test] {
  display:block;
  -webkit-perspective: 800px;
  perspective: 800px;
}

.reversible {
  position: relative;
  width: 250px;
  margin: 50px auto;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -webkit-transition: transform 1s ease;
  transition: all 1s
}

input[type=checkbox]:checked + label .reversible {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.reversible .card {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}


.tile-front {
  z-index: 2;
}

.tile-back {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY( 180deg);
  transform: rotateY( 180deg);
}

.card-body {
  font-size: 2rem;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
}
.card-footer {
  font-size: 2rem;
}


.card {
  background-color: #58AA3F;
  height: 20rem;
  transition: all .8s ease;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  border-radius: 5px;
  overflow: hidden;
  box-shadow: 0 1.5rem 4rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);

}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="test"/>
<label for="test">
  <div class="reversible">
     <div class="card tile-back">
        <div class="card-body">
            <p>Click to display back</p>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="card tile-front">
         <div class="card-body">
            <p>Click to display front</p>
         </div>
      </div>
</div>
</label>
```

<sub>Свободный перевод ответа [How can I make a card flip with css click-event using an input box?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52239732/7394871) от участника  [@enxaneta](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7897395/enxaneta).</sub>